# How do I expand the Preview or Render range in the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

[image: https://imgur.com/a/bhAcj0N]

I'm new to Blender and I want to know how to expand the Preview or Render range in the VSE?

Comment: The mouse scroll wheel or numpad + / - if you don't use a mouse should do it

Comment: see where it ends just after 4 seconds? I want to expand playback to include more than 4 seconds, the scroll wheel and +- numpad will zoom in and out but won't expand playback @Gorgious
sorry if I'm not explaining it properly, i'm a new contributor please ask if you need more explanation.

Comment: Oh, okay, you need to set the "End" frame to a higher value. You can change that in the lower right corner of the sequencer viewport

Comment: I see, how do I tag this question answered? You have answered it. @Gorgious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Preview or Render range by using these functions in the View menu:

[image]

Or use these values in the Timeline header:

[image]

The button with the alarm clock will let you switch between Preview and Render range values.

Comment: You say "Render range", but that function doesn't appear in capture image and it doesn't exist in Blender . Do you know if there is a way to do it?

Comment: I nickname Frame Range to Render Range, since this is the range that'll be rendered, it'll also be the preview range, when the preview range isn't set. In other words there are two range types in Blender the Frame Range and the Preview Range.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you said. "Render range" is "range of the render", not as I understood: "to render range". I was needing "to render preview range"... and that command does not exist... but "Sequence Render Animation" does and it is very usefull for me: so much faster than normal render and it can render the Preview Range !!